# Speed up mongo search & read queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, caching, mongoid

I have a problem with speeding up page load.
The page is actually a search page with predefined search parameters (we have around 100k or 200k) predefined search parameters sets. 
Currently each search page load takes up around 6 second or more to display the results. I need it to work faster.
What strategies are suitable in my case? And what profiling tools you used to with Mongo and can recommend?
Is there something I can do except just caching all predefined search pages? (I believe it's crazy to cache 200k pages).

P.S.> After setProfilingLevel to 2 for my db I got the following "long" queries, e.g.:

```
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=hipmunk_development collection=regions selector={"$query"=>{"region1_latin"=>"Central", "level"=>2, "$and"=>[{"hasc"=>{"$ne"=>"TH.BM"}}]}, "$orderby"=>{"popularity"=>-1}} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 464.6890ms
```

while others take 0.1 - 3.0 sec to implement.

I'm not so expert in MongoDB. Can you advices what can critically affect queries time? And what speedup strategies I can adopt? (I'm interested in both non-caching optimisation and caching strategies)

Comment: What's the explain of that query? Do you display all results? Or maybe you use paging (in which case, `limit` is missing)?

Comment: Indexes can affect greatly the result performance. In case you have multiple indexes created, you'd want to give MongoDB a _hint_ to use _specific_ index. Also, does your dataset fit in memory? If not, you may consider bumping up the specs of your server...